# Tying aux track automation to a region?

Tags: logic-pro

I produce long-form audio dramas using Logic Pro X and one snag I've occasionally hit is when I've needed to use aux track automation. My workflow involves frequent changes to the overall timeline,  usually with "Select all following" and dragging everything back or forward (accepting the question to move automation). This works great except when I have aux track automation. Since this automation is not tied to a region, it doesn't get moved correctly, so I have to manually fix this up later. I have tried to limit how much I use bus automation as a result, which is a shame.

How can I tie aux track automation to a region so that I can select it in the way I've described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question, Dom!

Luckily, in Logic Pro X you can use regions on Aux Tracks. AFAIK, you can place MIDI regions on Aux Tracks, but not Audio. (In fact, this is really helpful for controlling Multi-Output Instruments or sending MIDI to more than one separate instrument.)

Anyway, this means that you can create a region and attach your automation to it. I would suggest simply:

- right-clicking on the Aux Track you want to automate (in the Arrange Window, not the Track Header).
- selecting "Create Empty MIDI region", to place a short region on this track.
- extending the region to the length required for all your automation.
- writing in your automation.

Just one thing, it is important to either:

- write the MIDI into the Piano Roll window or,
- click on where it says "Track" in the Track Header, so that it changes to "Region".

This will make sure the automation stays attached to the region and not the track.

Comment: Great, and so obvious... I just never thought of these in terms of MIDI, since there's no MIDI data involved. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for accepting so quickly! BTW, you can upvote the answer as well if it worked for you... ;)